# Include a jQuery page within a main jQuery page

Tags: php, jquery, include

I am new to jQuery. Basically I have a main page (with jQuery) and I want to include in a div another page that also has jQuery. 
What I do is write in that particular div this code:

```
<?php
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $path .= "/ong/new/index.php";
   include_once($path);
?>
```

If I do this the jQuery in the child page stops working. The jQuery functions in the main page also stops working, but if I remove this link

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

from the child page it works in the main page.

So, what am I doing wrong? How should you include a jQuery page in another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are including jQuery multiple times. You could make small script to check if jQuery is present on the page, and only if is not present, load it:

```
// 'load-jquery.js'
window.onload = function () {
  if (window.jQuery === undefined) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'path/to/jquery.min.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script); // load jQuery
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

js

```
$('#result').load('<?php echo $path; ?>', function(data) {
  $(this).append(data);
});
```